# Best practice for loading webpage with long server side script

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, google-app-engine

What is the current best practice and method of loading a webpage (that has 10 - 15 seconds worth of server side script).

- User clicks a link > server side runs > html page is returned (blank
  page for 10 - 15 seconds).
- User clicks a link > html page is immediately returned (with progress
  bar) > AJAX post request to the server side > complete script > return result to
  html.
- Other options (threading?)

I am running Google App Engine (Python) Standard Environment.

Comment: Other option would be to cache the server response. otherwise load it via ajax for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way we're doing it is using the Ajax approach (the second one) which is what everyone else does.
You can use Task Queues to run your scripts asynchronously and return the result to front end using `FCM` (`Firebase Cloud Messaging`).
You should also try to break the script into multiple task queues to make it run faster.

Comment: thanks noob, glad to head the ajax approach is most commonly used. It's been a while since I have used ajax, so wasn't sure if there was a better approach. I will check out Task Queues also. Thanks!

Comment: Ajax is basically built on the philosophy that we should show something to user as soon as possible, even if the relevant data is not there yet. We can show a loader or something to show that the request has been accepted and will be processed. So that the user doesn't move away from the page and waits a little bit more.

Answer (score 2):

Best Practice would be for the the script to not take 10-15 seconds.

What is your script doing? Is it generating something that you can pre-compute and cache or save in Google Cloud Storage?

If you're daisy-chaining datastore queries together, is there something you can do to make them happen async in tandem?

If it really has to take 10-15 seconds, then I'd say option 2 is must:

> User clicks a link > html page is immediately returned (with progress bar) > AJAX post request to the server side > complete script > return result to html.

Comment: Many thanks Alex for the response. I think there is a bit of daisy-chaining which could be improved. I will try optimise, but I don't think it will reduce it significantly. Each script that runs is unique to the user running it (i.e it is doing tasks specific to that user), so don't believe I could pre-compute or cache either.